# Problem running PyQt code in Qgis3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

I am in my first steps in PyQt and I face difficulties in how to run the following code within QGIS console. I want to create a simple window, but nothing happens. I change **main** by **console** and then QGIS crashes. Any help is welcome.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

def main():
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  w = QWidget()
  w.resize(250, 150)
  w.move(300, 300)
  w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
  w.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: i think in QGIS you can't use an application object, because qgis itself is a QtApplication. Try to execute lines 6-10 alone and you'll see a widget on the screen. To have a full functional dialog, you'll need to a have something like a qgis-plugin. To work with pyqt only, try an standalone python shell or an ide.

Comment: Many thanks Andreas for your clarifications. In fact, I am used to write my codes in Notepad++ and run them in QGis console. As you mentioned, it is much better to create a QGis-plugin. What is the steps to follow to achieve this task easily?

Comment: try the qgis plugin "plugin builder", there is also a tutorial on this topic, but not for qgis3 (some steps are different). But Plugin Builder will  guide you through the process...

Comment: I put my comments into an answer, accept it if you like!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS you can't use an application object, because qgis itself is a QtApplication. Try to execute lines 6-10 alone and you'll see a widget on the screen. To have a full functional dialog, you'll need to a have something like a qgis-plugin. To work with pyqt only, try an standalone python shell or an ide.

For plugin creation, you use the qgis plugin "plugin builder", there is also a tutorial on this topic (http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html), but it doesn't cover qgis3 (some steps are different). But Plugin Builder will guide you through the process...